# How to install newest Ruby version without Homebrew?

Tags: mojave, ruby

I am using macOS Mojave. My work account has no administration privileges because of known macOS vulnerability. I have separate admin account. I have just tried to update Ruby to the newest version following documentation on https://www.ruby-lang.org. I have tried to install Homebrew manage Ruby upgrade but it wants my account to have admin privileges. Is there any other way to install Ruby?

Comment: The recommended way is "switch to your admin account, install ruby, switch back". Would this work for you?

Comment: Most installations will require admin privileges. As nohillside suggests: either use your admin username and password in the dialog that asks for authentication, or switch accounts for the installation. Also - what 'known vulnerability'?

Answer (score 1):

Use a Ruby version management tool. This class of tool allows you to install and switch between multiple versions of Ruby without needing administrator permissions and without overwriting the operating system installed version:

- [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv)
- [Ruby Version Manager (RVM)](https://rvm.io)
- [Unleash Ruby (URU)](https://bitbucket.org/jonforums/uru/src/master/)
- [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby)

### Example: rbenv

Install `rbenv` using either of the commands below…

```
# with curl
curl -fsSL https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer/raw/master/bin/rbenv-installer | bash

# alternatively, with wget
wget -q https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer/raw/master/bin/rbenv-installer -O- | bash
```

…then install the latest Ruby:

```
rbenv install 2.7.0-preview3
```

Answer (score 1):

@nohillside has reminded me in his comment:

> The recommended way is "switch to your admin account, install ruby, switch back".